# Core 2.2 base.SendAsync call in httpClientHandler doesn't return

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I got a real simple httpClientHandler that doesn't return from calling base.SendAsync.

What I am trying to do is grab an auth cookie so I know when to refresh the CouchDB auth.

There is no exceptions or anything else to indicate what is causing the problem.

Suggestions?

Here is the calling class:

```cs
public StdHttpClient(IConfiguration conf)
{
    configuration = conf;
    Client = new HttpClient(new AuthHandler());
}
public StdHttpClient()
{
    Client = new HttpClient(new AuthHandler());
}

private async Task<Boolean> GetAuthenticationCookie(Credentials credentials)
{
    var authReq = new { name = credentials.username, credentials.password };
    var authReqString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authReq);

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, sessionUri);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    request.Content = new StringContent(authReqString);
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
    MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage authResult = await Client.SendAsync(request);

    Console.WriteLine("GetAuth" + authResult.ToString()); //doesn't get here
    return authResult.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

The handler is:

```cs
public class AuthHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly int _maximumAmountOfRetries = 3;

    public AuthHandler() : base()
    {
    }

    public AuthHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      HttpResponseMessage response = null;

      response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
      Console.WriteLine("got response from sendasync");  //doesn't get here
      Console.WriteLine(response);

      return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was being stupid.  I was trying to call the auth as part of the initiation code from Program.cs so the Task was orphan.

Sorry about that.